# How to improve survrec plot in R?

Tags: r

I am trying to improve the display of a survfit**r** plot (as per the link below), with absolutely no luck. I get the impression I may have to redefine the plot function from scratch given I can't even change the xlab/ylab arguments without throwing warnings.

https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/survrec/versions/1.2-2/topics/plot.survfitr

I would like my survfit**r** object to be displayed like a singular event survival curve using with the ggsurvplot function. A good example can be seen here:

http://www.sthda.com/english/wiki/survival-analysis-basics

Any suggestions?

Code I have tried:

```
plot(surfvitrResult, conf.int=TRUE, prob=FALSE, xlim=c(0,xMax), ylim=c(0,yMax))
```

When I try to add in xlab or ylab I get a "formal argument xlab" warning; I understand why this is happening, that's not my issue. I would like the survfit**r** object to be plotted similar to its singular survfit object as per the link above and screen grabbed here:

[image]

Comment: When asking for help, you should include a simple [reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) with sample input and desired output that can be used to test and verify possible solutions. Show the code you tried. Is this specifically about the axis labels?

Comment: I've added a bit of code, but it's not so much a case of my code doesn't work but more of a question of hoping someone knows of the functionality required to reproduce the ggsurvplot function but for survfitr objects (rather than singular survfit objects). The survfitr.plot function by itself seems very basic.